# Add day to clock and date script written in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, date, time, clock

I need your help to add to this script the full name of the day (like Monday, Tuesday... etc...). I found scripts containing this

```
nameDay = new Array('Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato');
```

(I'm italian)

But I want to use the following script because is server side and it's cross browser compatible. I just want to add to it the name of the days.

This is the script that I want to edit. Thank you

```
<script>
var data = new Date();
data.setTime(<? echo time()*1000; ?>);
function clock()
{

var hou = data.getHours();
var min = data.getMinutes();
var sec = data.getSeconds();
if(hou<10){ ora= "0"+ora;}
if(min<10){ min= "0"+min;}
if(sec<10){ sec= "0"+sec;}
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = data.getDate()+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+data.getFullYear()+" - "+hou+":"+min+":"+sec;
    data.setTime(data.getTime()+1000)
    setTimeout("clock();",1000);
}

</script><body onload="clock()">
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: That script is **NOT** server side. You're getting the time from the server, but that's it. It would be much simpler to do in pure PHP.

Comment: @Ben Is it a live clock in pure php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.getDay() will give you the day index. 0 will be Sunday, 1 will be Monday and so forth.

```
<script>
var nameOfDay = new Array('Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato');
var data = new Date();
data.setTime(<?php echo time() * 1000; ?>);
function clock()
{

var hou = data.getHours();
var min = data.getMinutes();
var sec = data.getSeconds();
if(hou<10){ hou= "0"+hou;}
if(min<10){ min= "0"+min;}
if(sec<10){ sec= "0"+sec;}

var dayIdx = data.getDay();
var day = nameOfDay[dayIdx];

document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = day + " " + data.getDate()+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+data.getFullYear()+" - "+hou+":"+min+":"+sec;
    data.setTime(data.getTime()+1000)
    setTimeout("clock();",1000);
}

</script><body onload="clock()">
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), getDay() method will return the day.

so this is the code:

```
<script>
var data = new Date();
data.setTime(<?php echo time()*1000; ?>);
nameDay = new Array('Domenica','Lunedi','Martedi','Mercoledi','Giovedi','Venerdi','Sabato');
function clock()
{
    var hou = data.getHours();
    var min = data.getMinutes();
    var sec = data.getSeconds();
    var day = data.getDay();
    if(hou<10){ ora= "0"+ora;}
    if(min<10){ min= "0"+min;}
    if(sec<10){ sec= "0"+sec;}
    day = nameDay[day];
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = data.getDate()+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+data.getFullYear()+" "+day+" - "+hou+":"+min+":"+sec;
    data.setTime(data.getTime()+1000)
    setTimeout("clock();",1000);
}

</script><body onload="clock()">
<div id="clock"></div>
```